# Get NFT's owner on chain

Tags: spl-token, anchor-spl

Was wondering what would be the best solution to get the owner of an NFT on chain.

I am trying to validate this as I need to run some fn on my program only if the signer is the owner of the NFT.

I guess I would have to use `spl_token` with a CPI but not sure how.

*Please note that I am looking for an on chain solution and not off chain, thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NFT is essentially a token and can be treated as such. If you're using anchor, you can simply use the owner of the account holding the token

```
ctx.accounts.nft_token_account.owner
```

that's the owner

you can check if the account actually holds the token using

```
let nft_amount = &ctx.accounts.nft_token_account.amount;
assert_eq!(nft_amount, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that the (Token account)[https://docs.rs/spl-token/latest/spl_token/state/struct.Account.html] also has the mint `Pubkey`. So I guess if I check that the mint equals the mint of the NFT I want to make the check for AND the signer equals the `owner` then it's safe to assume that the signer actually own the NFT. Is that correct?

Comment: correct  @Jaani