# How to authenticate or validate wallets or NFTs when executing solana instructions

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, sol-cerberus

I am building a Solana program using [Anchor](https://book.anchor-lang.com/) and I would like to know which is the recommended way to authenticate/validate users allowed to execute certain Solana instructions. For what I have seen so far the [Metaplex Token metadata program](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata) provides the NFT metadata required to validate the NFTs, but I couldn't find examples on [Solana's cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-create-an-nft).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Manual implementations

A brief question that calls for an in-depth answer, I think this has been asked many times before:

- [How to get NFT's owner](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/get-nfts-owner-on-chain)
- [How to validate NFT collection addresses](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5613/how-to-get-the-collections-public-key-out-of-certain-nft-in-anchor)

### Using Sol Cerberus (recommended)

Probably the quickest implementation and the most reliable option at the moment is using [Sol Cerberus](https://solcerberus.com/), an on-chain Solana authentication program funded by the [Solana Foundation](https://solana.org/) which allows you to create [access rules](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started/add-permissions/) and [assign roles](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started/assign-roles/) to the users of your program through a simple [user interface](https://solcerberus.com/app).

#### Integration

The integration is pretty straightforward and explained in [the docs](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started). In a nutshell you just need to do three things:

- [Assign roles](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started/assign-roles/) to your users (to their wallets or NFTs)
- [Add rules](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started/add-permissions/) (grant permissions to the assigned roles)
- [Add the corresponding rule to the instructions](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started/restrict-access/#restrict-access-to-anchor-instructions) of your Anchor program to limit the access.

Taking the [SC demo program](https://demo.solcerberus.com/) as an example, for creating a square it uses the `Add` permission on the `Square` resource. Therefore only the roles with the `Square -> Add` permission will be allowed to execute [the instruction](https://github.com/AnderUstarroz/sol-cerberus-demo/blob/main/programs/sol-cerberus-demo/src/lib.rs#L32-L35):

```
 # RUST
 use sol_cerberus_macros::rule;

 declare_id!("THE_PROGRAM_ID");

 #[program]
 pub mod sol_cerberus_demo {

     use super::*;

     #[rule(Square, Add)]
     pub fn add_square(ctx: Context<Add>, color: String, size: u16) -> Result<()> {
         instructions::add::add(ctx, "square", &color, size)
     }

 }
```

and in the frontend:

```
// Javascript

let solCerberus = new SolCerberus(connection, myWallet);
await myProgram.methods.addSquare(color, size)
     .accounts({
       demo: pdas.demoPda,
       ...(await solCerberus.accounts("Square", "Add")),
     })
     .rpc();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to validate the wallet address.

```
#[account(mut, constraint = signer.key() == "GEPxxxxx...".parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap())]
pub signer: Signer<'info>
```

This is way to verify NFT. As you know to verify the nft on Solana, we can use the creator address.

```
 let nft_metadata = Metadata::from_account_info(mint_metadata)?;

    if let Some(creators) = nft_metadata.data.creators {
        let mut valid: u8 = 0;
        for creator in creators {
            if creator.address == CREATOR.parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap() && creator.verified == true
            {
                valid = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if valid != 1 {
            return Err();
        }
    } else {
        return Err();
    };
```